# React useEffect is not getting triggered

Tags: reactjs

Here is my code:

**state initialization**

```
const [uncheckedColArr, setUncheckedColArr] = useState([]);
```

Control is reaching to the following function, and also consoling correctly.

```
const updateFilterValue = (columnName, fieldValue, checked) => {
    let tempUncheckedColArr = uncheckedColArr;
    if (tempUncheckedColArr[columnName] === undefined) {
        tempUncheckedColArr[columnName] = [];
    }
    tempUncheckedColArr[columnName] = _.xor(
        tempUncheckedColArr?.[columnName],
        [fieldValue]
    );
    console.log("uncheckedColArr1", uncheckedColArr);

    setUncheckedColArr(tempUncheckedColArr);
    console.log("tempUncheckedColArr", tempUncheckedColArr);
    console.log("uncheckedColArr2", uncheckedColArr);
};
```

But, it's not triggering following `useEffect` whenever `unCheckedArr` is updated from above function

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("uncheckedColArr", uncheckedColArr);
    uncheckedColArr.map((col) => {
        console.log("col", col);
    });
}, [uncheckedColArr]);
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a minimal component?  Also, do `console.log("tempUncheckedColArr", tempUncheckedColArr)` before `setUncheckedColArr(...)` to see if it's the same value being set (see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are updating your array is incorrect:

```
const updateFilterValue = (columnName, fieldValue, checked) => {


    let tempUncheckedColArr = [...uncheckedColArr]; //<=== this will create new array
    if (tempUncheckedColArr[columnName] === undefined) {
        tempUncheckedColArr[columnName] = [];
    }
    tempUncheckedColArr[columnName] = _.xor(
        tempUncheckedColArr?.[columnName],
        [fieldValue]
    );
    console.log("uncheckedColArr1", uncheckedColArr);

    setUncheckedColArr(tempUncheckedColArr);
    console.log("tempUncheckedColArr", tempUncheckedColArr);
    console.log("uncheckedColArr2", uncheckedColArr);
};
```

Comment: now its reached the `useEffect`, but I am not being able to `console.log('col',col)`. What I might be missing?